# doPost(e) how to immediately response HTTP 200 OK, then do long time function

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers

In Google App Script, need to send a HTTP received code within 3 seconds.

If there is no 3-second time-out:

```
function doPost(e) {
    //do stuff
    long_time_function ();
    //can response received simply with this
    //this will auto response received HTTP code: 200 to the request
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(); 
}
```

Now with 3-second time-out requirement: within 3s if not sending a HTTP received code, the waiting server will trigger an error.

```
function doPost(e) {
    //quickly response received?
    //then do stuff
    function longtime() {//long time job }
}
```

I tried googling but couldn't find any workaround without using external libraries:

I tried:

```
    function doPost(e) {
        //using
        ContentService.createTextOutput();
        //or tried with UrlFetchApp
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(response_url, ops);

        Utilities.sleep(8000);//test
       //then do stuff
        function longtime() {//long time job }
    }
```

But still could not fully the 3s time-out requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Google Apps Script does not support asynchronous execution. If you can delay the long running function to a minute or 2 then I can suggests a work around.
Inside doPost, create a time driven trigger which will run a function after 1 or 2 minute and then you return the response immediately.
Since the trigger is now created, it will automatically execute the function at scheduled time.

Here is an outline of code.

```
function longRunningFunction(){
  // Some code here to execute later
}

function doPost(e) {

  var now  = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+2);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('longRunningFunction').timeBased().at(now).create();

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('My Respnse')
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work though? Didn't Google impose a restriction where triggers cannot be created from a Web App? Even with the proper scopes I get an error that states I don't have permission to run the "newTrigger" function.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your guidance! It worked! For ref link:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

Comment: @DimuDesigns: after adding newTrigger, deploy your new web app. Google shall ask you to give more permission

Comment: I've done that (deployed a web app with a new version) but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DimuDesigns: I used **.timeBased().after(100).create();** to schedule to run the function after 100ms.

I published it from the Script Editor (on browser), with this: 
Project version: New
Execute the app as:Me (your email address)
You need to authorize the script before distributing the URL.
Who has access to the app:Anyone, event anonymous

Comment: Ohh...in my use-case I need the app to be restricted to google users so I can't use `"Anyone, even anonymous"`. My app relies on services whose usage quotas are leveraged against the effective user's account (not mine). So I guess that's why triggers are disabled. Bummer. But thanks for the help, at least I now have a clearer picture of how things work.