# doPost Timeout with a long running function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, timeout

In Google App Script, doPost(e) expects a response within 3 seconds, otherwise, it will trigger a timeout error.

```
function doPost(e) {
    //do stuff
    long_time_function (); \\takes longer than 3 seconds

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(); 
}
```

In another question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442261/doposte-how-to-immediately-response-http-200-ok-then-do-long-time-function/68391373#68391373)), the problem was partially solved by creating a trigger for another function that runs later.

```
function longRunningFunction(){
  // Some code here to execute later
}

function doPost(e) {

  var now  = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+2);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('longRunningFunction').timeBased().at(now).create();

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('My Respnse')
}
```

this already helped me a lot. However, I have one more addition to this problem that I can't figure out so far.

Is it possible to include the data in e (from doPost(**e**)) in the `LongRunningFunction()`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Save the data to the script properties in the `doPost()` function and access them in `longRunningFunction`.*

#### Example:

In the doPost, save the data you need to properties:

```
function doPost(e) {
  const props = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
  const data = e.parameters.name // or whatever
  props.setProperty("propertyName", data)

  const now  = new Date()
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 2)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('longRunningFunction').timeBased().at(now).create()

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('My Respnse')
}
```

Then access it in `longRunningFunction`:

```
function longRunningFunction() {
  const props = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
  const data = props.getProperty("propertyName")

  // do stuff with data
}
```

#### References:

- [Properties Service | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)